# Accessing Cookies across Sub-domain

Tags: cookies, subdomain, httponly

We have cookies added by the current website say *www.example.com*. Cookie domain of those cookies is one of the following when viewed in browser,

- www.example.com (are also marked as HostOnly)
- .example.com
- .www.example.com

Now, we are creating a sub-domain say *test.example.com* and we need that sub-domain to have access to all the cookies added by www.example.com.

Please help in understanding which of the cookies will NOT be shared and why.

Also, another query regarding cookies is - HttpOnly. Will cookies marked as HttpOnly be not available across sub-domains?

Comment: duplicate: [Share cookie between subdomain and domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain). The `HttpOnly` attribute is an instruction to the web-browser to not allow javascript to access it.

Comment: Thanks Ryan! Can you also please brief me on HostOnly cookies? Can they be shared across subdomains?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share cookie between subdomain and domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain)